# Can no longer produce PDF from Google Sheets spreadsheet for some of the users

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export

For almost a year we have been using the below code to export a Google Sheets sheet (held in `theSheetName`) to a PDF named as specified in `InboundID`.

This last week, one at a time various users can no longer produce the PDF.  I get a failure at the line containing "var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);" with the error being:

> "Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed."

And sure enough, the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is returning HTML instead of a PDF.  Again, only for some users. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why my users might be seeing this?

```
function sendPDFToDrive(theSheetName, InboundID) 
{
  var theSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSpreadsheetId = theSpreadSheet.getId();
  var thisSheetId = theSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(theSheetName).getSheetId();  
  var url_base = theSpreadSheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var theOutFileName = "GASFILE_M_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8997) + 1000) + '.pdf'
  //export as pdf
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   
      + (thisSheetId ? ('&gid=' + thisSheetId) : ('&id=' + theSpreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&scale=2' // 1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=true'  // hide gridlines
      + '&printnotes=false' // don't show notes
      + '&fzr=true';       // repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  // Setup options
  var options = 
  {
    headers: 
    {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  // Build the file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(theOutFileName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ABC123FooBarID");
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob); //Create a new file from the blob
  newFile.setName(InboundID + ".pdf"); //Set the file name of the new file
  newFile.makeCopy(folder);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having this exact problem. After some debugging I saw that my URL was being created incorrectly.

My code was nearly identical to yours. Where I found the culprit was the following line:

```
var url_base = theSpreadSheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
```

This was not actually clearing out the 'edit' to the end of the line like it had for years. I cannot say why this is, but the proof was in the logs. So, instead I crafted the url by hand:

```
var   url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+'/';
```

This seemed to solve the problem. This is not a perfect futureproof resolution, because if Google changes how the URLs are crafted, this will fail. But it works for now.

I hope this helps. You can send the url your code is creating to logs and check them to see if you have the same issue I did.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Jesse's accepted answer - the culprit is definitely in this line:

```
var url_base = theSpreadSheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
```

The reason why the `replace(/edit$/,'')` call no longer clears out `edit` like before is because the URL returned by `theSpreadSheet.getUrl()` used to end with `edit`, but now returns a URL with additional parameters on the end - `ouid=1111111111111111111111&urlBuilderDomain=yourdomain.com`.

While rebuilding the URL entirely should also work, you can also patch the script with some small changes to the regular expression. Instead of looking for `edit$` (meaning `edit` as the final characters in the string), you can look for edit + any additional characters like so:

```
var url_base = theSpreadSheet.getUrl().replace(/edit.*$/,'');
```

Comment: your regex won't work for 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tc2WnuWmQZZYfXeditVUStHyNmUP5K9rkTiJXzTGoA/edit?param1=1&param2=2'

Comment: @Kos Why not?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: @TheMaster because spreadsheet ids are always random letters and numbers, there could be `edit` in the id

Comment: @Kos Nice.`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Good point, @Kos - in this case the regex could be modified to `.replace(/\/edit.*$/,'');` and the `url_ext` string modified to begin with the initial `/`. This still leaves an edge case where your spreadsheet ID begins with the characters `edit` which I suppose could be avoided by searching for the `?` after `edit` as well.

Comment: @bcolbert yeah, `edit` in the beginning of id is another edge case, hopefully can be fixed with regex, but there another way: `.split('/edit').slice(0, -1).join('/edit')`

Answer (score 1):

better also avoid using comma for the last property of the header pointing below:

-- 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), --