# Why is the pdf I've sending through google sheets by using goole script always broken?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that sends a spreadsheet as pdf, and whenever I run it, the pdf file is unreadable (even the image on the signature is broken), however, when I use a different account, it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can no longer produce PDF from Google Sheets spreadsheet for some of the users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413712/can-no-longer-produce-pdf-from-google-sheets-spreadsheet-for-some-of-the-users)